# Flutter basics - fromJson factory method typecast int to dynamic

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

Getting compile-time error `The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.dartargument_type_not_assignable` on `userId: json['userId'],` and others.

Ref - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

```
Dart VM version: 2.8.4 (stable)
Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2)
```

Comment: Try casting the id to an int. (json['id'] as int). It would be great to create an utility function for the same. If the cast isn't successful then onCastError assign it some default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Album {
final dynamic userId;
final dynamic id;
final String title;

Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Album(
  userId: json['userId'],
  id: json['id'],
  title: json['title'],
);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to resolve it -

**1st** - Using `json_serializable` and `json_annotation` package which does the 2nd way behind the scenes -

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'http.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AlbumFromJson(json);
}
```

Run - `flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs` to generate the part file.

**2nd** - Using `as` keyword to typecast using specific types -

```
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'] as int,
      id: json['Id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```